# Is it advisable to start new threads (Using programatic means) within a Kafka Streams Application?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are developing a Kafka Streams application using the low level Processor API.

As per the documentation on Kafka, all threading and parallelism is handled by Stream threads and stream tasks. The parallelism is also scalable using partitions on the topics.

The current code looks like:

```
public class Processor implements Processor<K, V> {

@Override
  public void process(String key, V value) {

      //Do processing on the stream thread itself
      ...

      // Write back to output topic
      context.forward(key, updatedValue)
    }); 
  }
}
```

However, is it recommended under any circumstances to create our own threads for doing the actual processing? This would mean utilising Kafka Streams API mainly for consuming the data from the topic and not for actual processing. The actual processing will happen in the new threads that are invoked after the initial data consumption in the Kafka stream thread.

Sample Processor in the topology:

```
public class Processor implements Processor<K, V> {

@Override
  public void process(String key, V value) {

  //Spawn new thread to do the processing
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
      String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
      System.out.println("Hello " + threadName);

      //Do more processing
      ...

      // Write back to output topic
      context.forward(key, updatedValue)
    }); 
  }
}
```

I have tried the most basic code for this but cannot be certain on whether it is intervening with automatic functionality provided by Kafka. For e.g. auto commit offsets, timeouts etc.

Or is it always better to stick to the default behaviour already provided by Kafka streams and utilise stream thread for quick processing of data?

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to start your own threads, because this breaks Kafka Streams' fault-tolerance guarantees. If `process()` returns, Kafka Streams assumes that a message was fully processed and all potential output message were sent via `forward()`. For this case, Kafka Streams might commit the input record offset.

However, if you process the message in a background thread, and the thread fails processing, Kafka Streams would not know anything about it, and hence, offsets might be committed even if a failure occurs and the message would be lost.

Also, a background thread is not allowed to call `forward()` after `process()` returned. If `forward()` is called "outside" of `process()` Kafka Streams will throw an exception.

It is not impossible to use your own background threads and to preserve at-least-once processing guarantees, however, it is rather complicated and thus not recommended.

Answer (score -2):

Kafka streams uses the kafka consumer API to consume the messages from a kafka topic. This means that even if you spawn multiple threads to consume messages, the extra threads will stay idle.

For instance, if your topic has 5 partitions, even if you spawn 10 threads to read from the topic, the kafka consumer api will only make use of 5 threads to read from the topic and the remaining threads will be idle.

You can define the number of threads to be spawned while defining your streams config.

```
Properties streamsConfig = new Properties();

streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 1); //Here number of threads being spawned per kafka streams app node is 1
```

So if your topic has 10 partitions and your kafka streams app is deployed on two nodes, the NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG would then be 5.

Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that we can use the NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG. I have now updated the question with code samples to clarify the question further.